# Get values from multiple select list using KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

html

```
<select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
<br/>
<select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: sendMe, enable: selectedChoice" Value="Click Me"/>
```

KnockoutJS

```
var CountryModel = function(data){
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this
   self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();

   self.countries = ko.observableArray([
        new CountryModel({id: "1", name: "Russia"}),
        new CountryModel({id: "2", name: "Qatar"})]);
    self.sendMe = function(){


        alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedCountryId: this.selectedChoice()}));
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I have two issues:

1. How do I make the select lists independent?
2. How do I get the selectedvalue from each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need 2 separate observables in your viewmodel to store the selected value of each list;
here `selectedChoice1` and `selectedChoice2`.

See the runnable example below.

```js
var CountryModel = function(data){
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this
   self.selectedChoice1 = ko.observable();
   self.selectedChoice2 = ko.observable();

   self.countries = ko.observableArray([
        new CountryModel({id: "1", name: "Russia"}),
        new CountryModel({id: "2", name: "Qatar"})]
        );
   self.sendMe = function(){    
        alert(ko.toJSON({ 
            "selectedCountryId1": this.selectedChoice1(), 
            "selectedCountryId2": this.selectedChoice2() 
            }));
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice1, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
<br/>
<select data-bind="options: countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice2, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: sendMe, enable: (selectedChoice1() && selectedChoice2())" Value="Click Me"/>
```